# Finding explicit terms for $U(x,y)$ and $V(x,y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

We are given $u = U(x,y)$ and $v = V(x,y)$ and $x = e^u \cos v$ and $y = e^u \sin v$. We are to find explicit terms form $U(x,y)$ and $V(x,y)$. I have tried some bruteforce-techniques, but I am lagging behind in the course and am not sure how to proceed. You may assume familiarity with partial derivatives, gradients and most standard techniques of differentiation in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formally:
$$
\tan v = \frac{y}{x}
$$
and therefore
$$
u = \log \frac{x}{\cos v} = \ldots
$$

Comment: Oh, one can just bruteforce it like that? I expected more of a trick.

Comment: $u=\log\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Comment: As @Lotman remarks, these are essentially polar coordinates $\rho=e^u$ and $\theta = v$.